# outlook add-in 2010 how do I know that the user presses Reply button?

Tags: button, outlook, reply

I'm developing an outlook 2010 add-in in c#/.net. I have some items that I need to export to a specific location from inbox let's say. But in the same time when the user replies to this mail item (that was previous exported - I change the MessageClass when export it), I need to export the reply too when the user sends the reply. I catch the new inspector event and set the send event to my item, but I cannot figure out how can I be sure that the user presses Reply and not Forward for example?! I cannot find any property in the inspector that can tell me for sure that the Reply button was pressed.

Do you have any ideas?!

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to achieve this. Assuming you already checked if it was a new message or sent message (*via [`MailItem.Sent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868242)*), you can just check whether there are any recipients specified (*via [`MailItem.To`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff860378.aspx) or [`MailItem.Recipients`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865320)*) to know whether the message is a **Forward** or **Reply**.

```cs
bool isReply = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(MailItem.To) || MailItem.Recipients.Count > 0 ;
```

Comment: I just need to know that the inspector is reply window, that's it and it works. Thanks a lot and I cannot believe that I didn't think about this solution! Thanks

Comment: Glad it helped you out! Please [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/23139/171414) so others can benefit.